# Jquery delay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please tell me why my function is not executing, after my images are displayed?

```
 $("#screen").css("background-image", "url('screens/animated/077.gif')").delay(5000).queue(function() {
       $("#screen").css("background-image", "url('screens/animated/078.gif')").delay(5000).queue(function() {
           buttonClick(16);
       });

    });
```

Don't know why it won't call my buttonClick(16); function.

Comment: Is it defined? Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: have you tried some simple debugging like calling the buttonClick outside the delay functions?

Answer (score 1):

You could just animate instead dude? animate() you can pass a time to and also it has a callback function, so once the first animation is complete you can run more code, i.e.

```
$(this).animate(function(){
    //Do animation
},1000,function(){
    //Animation is complete, do something else like the next animation
    $(this).animate(function(){
        //Another animation to run once the first is complete
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't dequeue.

```
$("#screen").css("background-image", "url('screens/animated/077.gif')").delay(5000).queue(function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url('screens/animated/078.gif')").delay(5000).queue(function () {
        $(this).dequeue();
        buttonClick(16);
    }).dequeue();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The queue function receives a param that you should call when the next function should run.
Example:

```
$().queue(function (next) {
    // Do what you need
    next();
});
```